# ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED doesn't work

Tags: java, android, apk

I have a small problem in Androidstudio with my battery status app. I have the following receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

But the `PowerConnectionReceiver` only work with the ACTION_POWER_* event. The battery change event is not working

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) 
        Toast.makeText(context, "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) 
        Toast.makeText(context, "not loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Toast.makeText(context, "test toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}



Intent intent = getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to instantiate your `PowerConnectionReceiver`.

```
Intent intent = getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

should be

```
Intent intent = getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(PowerConnectionReceiver() , new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

Even better would be to keep a reference, so you can unregister again in `onStop()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but it has still no effect. The ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED event is even working without the registration

Comment: indeed, the docs say that you don't need to pass the receiver. Weird, that it doesnt work. Are you sure, that the battery changed? Well, actually you should get the event when you just register the receiver...

Comment: @Chrasonier did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

There is a restriction that some Broadcasts(e.g. `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`)
sent by the system cannot be received by statically defined broadcast receivers.